# What's the best way to let an iPhone vibrate multiple times when locked?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to have an iPhone vibrate multiple consecutive times in the Notification Center. 
While researching on this, I found several posts saying Apple only allows a single alert to be fired and therefore only one vibration per alert.

I recently saw a WhatsApp call coming in on my phone and the thing just went crazy. I try to achieve the same behavior. 
One possible solution would be to just delete and create notifications over and over again, but I am pretty sure Apple will just decline this behavior.

This is how this could look like:

```
var interval = 10
var i = 0
while(i < interval) {
    sendNotification(message)
    sleep(1)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    i += 1
}
sendNotification(message)

func sendNotification(text: String) {

let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "This is a test"
notification.alertAction = "Stop Alarm" 
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName 
notification.category = "ALERT"

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

So, what's the best way to achieve this and comply with Apples guidelines?

Comment: Does you app receive phone calls? An incoming call alert is not the same as a local notification.

Comment: It's more like an alarm clock thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not seem possible. From [iOS Human Interface Guidelines - Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/notifications/):

> Note that you can’t programmatically cause the device to vibrate when
>   a notification is delivered, because the user has control over whether
>   alerts are accompanied by vibration.

I'd imagine Apple allows *some* popular apps to achieve this though, like WhatsApp, YouTube, etc...

Comment: Apparently these apps you are listing are using remote notifications, not local. Unfortunately it seems not possible to do this locally.